# How to trigger jScrollPane scroll to bottom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I have searched a lot, but couldnt find any thing that could help me. I need a javascript event that fires when the scrollbar has reached near bottom. I remember with out jScrollPane i used to do it with binding scroll event of the div and inside the event it does some calculation with scrolltop and height etc to see if the scrolling has been done to/near bottom. I cant find any similar thing in Jscrollpane's scroll bar. I found a couple of similar questions, but they were in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a page describing those events [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html)

```
 $('.scroll-pane').
    bind('jsp-scroll-y', function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
         // some basic math here            
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i found the page after posting the question.